# Meteor+Cordova - "deviceready has not fired" on Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, meteor

I am trying to use AngularJS with Meteor generated Android app, but on launching I see the following logs:

> I20150214-10:02:23.331(5.5) (android:meteor_cordova_loader.js:12) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Error reading version file Error: Failed to resolve entry: file:///data/data/com.id5njc0uqfdxry1j5uk4s/files/meteor/version
>   I20150214-10:02:23.334(5.5) (android:meteor_cordova_loader.js:12) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Couldn't load from the manifest, falling back to the bundled assets.
>   I20150214-10:02:23.982(5.5) (android:meteor_cordova_loader.js:12) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Loading from url: http://meteor.local
>   I20150214-10:02:33.168(5.5) (android:http://meteor.local/cordova.js:1154) deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
>   I20150214-10:02:33.170(5.5) (android:http://meteor.local/cordova.js:1147) Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
>   I20150214-10:02:33.171(5.5) (android:http://meteor.local/cordova.js:1147) Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
>   I20150214-10:02:33.172(5.5) (android:http://meteor.local/cordova.js:1147) Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded

and angular does not get initialized. Can anyone suggest a workaround?

I've opened a Github issue for this as well [#3711](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3711)

The device is a Samsung GT S7392 running Android 4.1.2

Comment: are you trying to launch on simulator or real device?

Comment: I'm running on a physical device.

Comment: wich device? and android version?

Comment: The device is Samsung GT-S7392 and the Android version is 4.1.2

Comment: Yep i asume that check [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2655) GitHub issue on @crapthings last comment

Comment: Yeah I checked that, no solution is mentioned for it yet.

Comment: Still facing this issue on the latest version of the meteor(2.0), any updates?

cordova plugins: cordova-plugin-android-permissions@1.0.0 cordova-plugin-appinfo-sync@0.2.0 cordova-plugin-qr-barcode-scanner@8.0.3

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reason how may cause this kinda of issue.

Seems like running android on old devices can be a problem take a look into this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2655)

Im pretty sure that `deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds`its kinda a warning message.

Check how many packages you have installed on the app.

Are you running on Phisical device? or adb?

Try with `--verbose` option to and put the logs here.

like this

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server=your-url-app --verbose
```

Tell me if works