# Meteor Cordova on Android Errors

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor

I'm getting a number of errors when running my Meteor app on Android via Cordova

=> Started your app.
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
(android:http://meteor.local/cordova.js:1169) deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
(android:http://meteor.local/cordova.js:1162) Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded
(android:http://meteor.local/client/templates/analytics/types/template.bagging_and_tagging_analytics.js:2) Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
(android:http://meteor.local/client/templates/analytics/types/template.biological_notice_analytics.js:2) Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
(android:http://meteor.local/client/templates/analytics/types/template.farmer_triage_analytics.js:2) Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
(android:http://meteor.local/client/templates/analytics/types/template.fertilizer_application_analytics.js:2) Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
(android:http://meteor.local/lib/collections/blocks.js:1) Uncaught ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined
(android:http://meteor.local/lib/collections/forms.js:1) Uncaught ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined
(android:http://meteor.local/lib/collections/ground_db_users.js:1) Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined
(android:http://meteor.local/lib/collections/notifications.js:1) Uncaught ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined
(android:http://meteor.local/lib/helpers/get_connection_status.js:1) Uncaught ReferenceError: UI is not defined
(android:http://meteor.local/client/startup/connection_tracker.js:1) Uncaught ReferenceError: Tracker is not defined
(android:http://meteor.local/packages/multiply_iron-router-progress.js:52) Uncaught ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined
I20150522-00:30:55.484(3)? at Router.configure.waitOn (http://meteor.local/lib/router.js?a620a3574120a8292b544d367fc6fc742b854698:7:8)
I20150522-00:30:55.484(3)? at http://meteor.local/packages/iron_router.js?a427868585af16bb88b7c9996b2449aebb8dbf51:1199:36
I20150522-00:30:55.484(3)? at _.extend.withValue (http://meteor.local/packages/meteor.js?4dc9757b244a30bdf37a732ac4db4026ce56fb6b:981:17)
I20150522-00:30:55.485(3)? at hookWithOptions (http://meteor.local/packages/iron_router.js?a427868585af16bb88b7c9996b2449aebb8dbf51:1198:27)
I20150522-00:30:55.485(3)? at http://meteor.local/packages/iron_router.js?a427868585af16bb88b7c9996b2449aebb8dbf51:438:22
I20150522-00:30:55.485(3)? at Array.forEach (native)
I20150522-00:30:55.485(3)? at Function.*.each.*.forEach (http://meteor.local/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156:11)
I20150522-00:30:55.485(3)? at RouteController._runRoute (http://meteor.local/packages/iron_router.js?a427868585af16bb88b7c9996b2449aebb8dbf51:437:5)
I20150522-00:30:55.485(3)? at Function.Route.dispatch (http://meteor.local/packages/iron_router.js?a427868585af16bb88b7c9996b2449aebb8dbf51:844:18)

Comment: may i know your command to run on android device?

Comment: are you using deviceready. Instead of deviceready, invoke your code in `Meteor.startup` or templates `onRendered`

Comment: checkout this link https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "deviceready" instead of "deviceready" All my templates are using OnRendered and I don't have any functionality which relies on a Cordova/Phonegap plugin should wrap code in a Meteor.startup() block.

Comment: `if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    //cordova code
  });
}` this is my code. It works fine in my app

Comment: I have no cordova code or specific code that needs to run only in cordova

Comment: is your project working fine?. because look at his answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28512471/1560616. He said its kinda warning message

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure that's not it, I tried testing on the device Nexus 5 and noting. If I run the app in the web no issues

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined` is your error right?

Comment: Yes one of the errors

Answer (score 0):

All the errors were caused by the Meteor Message Format package. Once removed it compiled just fine.